# Access writing violation when using INVOKE

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

currently messing around with x86 assembly and I'm having some issues identifying the reason why the following code is causing a write access violation:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
main PROC
INVOKE minmax,
        OFFSET array,
        LENGTHOF array,
        OFFSET msg1,
        OFFSET msg2


main ENDP
```

Look at your proc carefully...  Your missing something, do you realize what?  Well, your missing a `ret` right before `main endp`!  Without a `ret` the cpu will continue executing what ever is after main endp.

```
main PROC
INVOKE minmax,
        OFFSET array,
        LENGTHOF array,
        OFFSET msg1,
        OFFSET msg2

ret
main ENDP
```

is correct

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently trying to store an SDWORD into a register, but it's getting converted to a huge number when I try to do so. Do you know how I can correctly store my value?